# Poisson distribution with rationals

Tags: probability-theory

We want to construct an infinitely divisible random variable $X$ supported on the rational numbers as follows:

Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable with some parameter $\lambda >0$
Let $R$ be any random variable supported on the rationals. Let $R_1$,$R_2$,$\dots$ be iid instances of $R$, independent of $N$.
Let $a$ be a fixed rational number

How can I write $X$ as $X=a+R_1+\dots+R_N$ ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say "how can I write". What are you trying to show?

Comment: @Bey Well I would like to express it as above in order to show that $X$ thus defined is infinitely divisible and $X$ is a.s rational.

Comment: So, your question is, is $X=a+\sum_1^N R_i,\; N\sim \textrm{Poi}(\lambda), X_i, a \in \Bbb{Q}$ rationally valued and infinitely divisible?

Comment: @Bey I know it is, I just don't know how to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rationality of $X$ is simple to prove for finite $N$, as the rationals form a field, so $x,y \in \mathbb{Q} \implies x+y \in \mathbb{Q}$. More generally, $\sum_1^N x_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ *iff* $N<\infty$.

A counterexample that rules out countable sums is $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (see [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem))

Since $P(N=\infty)=0$, $X\in \mathbb{Q}\; a.s.$

As for infinitely divisible, $X$ is infinitely divisible *iff*

$$X = \sum Y_i, \; \textrm{where}\;Y_i\sim F_Y$$

You defined $X$ to be:

$$X = a + \sum_1^N R_i, \; \textrm{where}\; R_i \sim F_R(r) $$

Hence, for a given $a,N$, we have:

$$X=\sum_1^N G_i,\; \mathrm{where}\; G_i \sim F_R(r-a/N)$$

The denseness of the rationals ensures this is true for every $N$.

So it will be infinitely divisible too.

Comment: I have one more questions: can every infinitely divisible random variable that is a.s. rational be written this way ?

Comment: @user43418 I am wary of making it a universal statement. Your construction results in an infinitely divisible a.s. rational rv. But it does not follow that ALL such rvs can be constructed this way. Basically, you've shown $A \implies B$ but you now want to claim $B \implies A$

Comment: No, I am asking if that is the case ?

Comment: @user43418 I know, and I am saying that I don't know if that general case is true...